# Teradata BTEQ error

Tags: teradata

I am trying to run the below bteq script in unix.

BTEQ -- Update.txt

---

```
 .LOGON i.p/username,password

 .set width 132
 .set errorout stdout

 sel date, time;

 .set maxerror 1

 Nonsequenced validtime 
 update SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1
 set ef_dtm = period( timestamp '1900-01-01 00:00:00.999999',     
 end(ef_dtm))
 where begin(ef_dtm) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
 and end(ef_dtm) = to_date('12/31/9999', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 

 .quit
```

---

But i am getting the below error

> *** Failure 3706 Syntax error: Invalid use of JSON entity reference         syntax on non-JSON type.
>               Statement# 1, Info =0
>
> Exiting BTEQ... RC (return code) = 8

Please note that if I run the update statement along with nonsequenced
valid time directly in SQL Assistant, it works without any issue. 
Can you please help me fix this?

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: There's a missing semicolon before the `.quit`. Btw, No need for Oracle-type `to_date('12/31/9999', 'mm/dd/yyyy')`, better use Standard SQL's `DATE '1999-12-31'` instead (Oracle supports it, too)

Comment: Even after putting the semicolon, i am facing the same error .

Answer (score 0):

User semicolon at the end of update statement.